# SSRS Expression- Adding Totals per page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

I need an expression to add a total per page in SSRS in the footer of the report. Click on link below to see screenshot.

So when users run SSRS, the first page must show a total for order qty , ship qty and subtotal for the first page only.

When users go to the second page, the it must show the total for order qty, ship qty and subtotal for the second page only as in the screenshot below.

The data region that is being used is a table region, and on the footer textboxes are being used to add totals for order qty, ship qty and subtotal.

Let me know if there is any expression that can do that and how I would add it to the footer. I thank you all in advance for helping !!

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ie00fb&s=8

Comment: Follow this blog that will give you what you want http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/09/running-totals-per-page-in-ssrs-to.html

Answer (score 1):

You can total the contents of a textbox on the page in the header or Footer using the expression =Sum(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value)

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220421(v=sql.110).aspx